# TSQL: How to deal with the WHERE clause when you may or not send parameters

Tags: t-sql, ef-core-2.1

This is something I'm doing in the code for filtering. How do I get the samething in a SPROC?

```
var projects = _context.Projects.AsQueryable();
if (parameterList.OfficeIds)
{
   projects = projects.Where(x => parameterList.OfficeIds.Contains( x.OfficeId));
}
var list = projects.ToListAsync();
```

I know how to send comma-separated values as parameters. My focus is more on how to apply the conditional **WHERE** clause in the SPROC.

When there are ids to lookup for, I can send something like `SqlParameter("@value1", value1), SqlParameter("@value2", value2)`

```
SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE OfficeId IN ({0})
```

Now what bout when there is not parameter to send, how do I deal with the **WHERE** clause?

Thanks for helping

Comment: So you know how to use a splitter with a comma-delimited list to get a table of values, right? You can use something like `... where exists ( select 42 from SplitFooIds as SFI where SFI.FooId = OuterQuery.FooId ) or not exists ( select 42 from SplitFooIds )`. The second part is `true` when the table has zero rows. (Assumption: An empty list of filter values means "all".) Additional reading: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this a lot at my work.

```
DECLARE @UserId int

SELECT *
FROM Users u
WHERE UserId = ISNULL(@UserId, u.UserId)
```

OR

```
DECLARE @CSV VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT * 
FROM Projects p 
WHERE P.OfficeId IN (select * from dbo.fn_Splitter(@CSV)) OR @CSV IS NULL
```

So if you pass a value for the parameter, it will use the parameter's value and filter your rows. If you don't pass a value for the parameter, or it is null, it will just ignore WHERE clause and return all the records from the table.

Comment: I'm not using `=` but rather `IN`.

Comment: Just replace = with IN

Comment: Do u mean something like `WHERE UserId IN(ISNULL(@UserId, u.UserId))` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, test locally with sample data, and see if it works

Comment: as I said earlier, this is working fine for one value. However, when there are more values to be sent to the SPROC, I can't figure out how to pack more than one value in a single local variable. I've tried with a couple of GUID `'A71DE4CE-AD2C-48CC-A266-0123D66F7A26', ''''291781FD-2CCA-4797-A78A-025E8ADD0F8E'''`. I still got an error as the this is not a valid GUID.

Comment: Very interesting, I don't know if you have an access to modify sql code, but very simplistically, you could do it like this:
`DECLARE @CSV VARCHAR(8000) 
IF @CSV IS NOT NULL 

 SELECT * 
 FROM Projects p
 WHERE P.OfficeID IN  (SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_Splitter (@CSV))

ELSE
 
 SELECT * FROM Projects p`
I am working on how to do it in one statement

Comment: Is your parameter an int or varchar?

Comment: It turned out to be rather simpler than I thougt:
`DECLARE @CSV VARCHAR(8000)  


SELECT * 
FROM Projects p

WHERE P.OfficeId IN  (select * from dbo.fn_splitter(@csv)) or @csv is null`

Comment: Ok, great. added it to the body of the answer itself